# How to remove the padding on a dropdown-menu

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am looking for a way to remove a padding on "dropdown-menu" `<ul>` tag when the list is empty, so nothing shows instead of narrow space corresponding to the padding. 
I don't want to do `.dropdown{padding: 0}`, because it will remove the necessary padding when it's not empty. But `.dropdown:empty{padding:0}` doesn't work since the content is not empty, only filtered by an *ngIf (I guess, though I know that Angular removes the element from the DOM).

```
<ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li *ngFor="let option of options">
      <span *ngIf="option.condition;then template1 else template2">
      </span>
      <ng-template #template1>some content</ng-template>
      <ng-template #template2>some content</ng-template>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You probably have good knowledge in javascript or/and jQuery so just check if .dropdown-menu or other div have childs ... if now, set .css('padding','0px')

Comment: Remove the padding from `.dropdown-menu` and use the padding on the `li`'s or content inside of them instead so there will be no padding if there are no `li`'s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace the `padding` on parent with `margins` on first and last child:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
   padding-top: 0;
   padding-bottom: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu > li:first-child {
   margin-top: 15px;
}
.dropdown-menu > li:last-child {
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Note the selectors here are generic. You'll need to change them to apply to your specific example and not affect other instances of `.dropdown-menu` that perhaps should not be affected.
Also, `15px` is a generic size. You should use *the same value and unit* you now have in `.dropdown-menu` top and bottom padding.

Comment: You gave me the idea to work with the content instead of 'dropdown-menu' that I was stubbornly trying to manipulate.  :last-child/:first-child didn't work,  but putting template1 and template2 contents' classes spans' margin-top:0.5em ; margin-bottom:0.5em worked!